# Why are my log messages nonsense when I log through ILogger, both with and without Serilog?

Tags: .net-core, logging, serilog, ilogger

I am writing a .NET 7 application, and my ultimate goal is to output JSON logs to the console. I can do this using the Microsoft's `ILogger` components, and this seems to be highly idiomatic, at least when ASP.NET is involved. I am in fact *not* creating an ASP.NET application, but instead a command-line application that will run in a container (thus the JSON logging output).

I noticed in my output that my log entries sometimes look quite odd, depending on how I create them. For example, if I write a log entry like this:

```cs
var state = new[] {
    KeyValuePair.Create<string, object>("state-key-1", "state-value-1"),
    KeyValuePair.Create<string, object>("state-key-2", 2),
};

_logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, new EventId(12, "twelve"), state, null, (state, ex) => "This message came from _logger.Log(...); it has no formatted values.");
```

I would get a log entry output that looks like this:

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "2023-03-09T18:27:55",
  "EventId": 12,
  "LogLevel": "Error",
  "Category": "ConsoleApplication",
  "Message": "This message came from _logger.Log(...); it has no formatted values.",
  "State": {
    "Message": "System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair\u00602[System.String,System.Object][]",
    "state-key-1": "state-value-1",
    "state-key-2": 2
  }
}
```

The State -> Message property is, of course, the `.ToString()` value for my `state` array. The actual state keys and values are there, so I can live with this, but the very strange message output makes me feel like I'm misunderstanding how this is meant to be used.

If I write log messages that I have defined using `LoggerMessage.Define(...)`, then my output looks much more like I would expect:

```cs
var lm = LoggerMessage.Define<string>(LogLevel.Error, new EventId(11, "eleven"), "This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: {formatted_value}");

lm(_logger, "my-formatted-value", null);
```

In this case, the output looks like this:

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "2023-03-09T18:27:55",
  "EventId": 11,
  "LogLevel": "Error",
  "Category": "ConsoleApplication",
  "Message": "This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: my-formatted-value",
  "State": {
    "Message": "This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: my-formatted-value",
    "formatted_value": "my-formatted-value",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: {formatted_value}"
  }
}
```

In this case, however, I cannot include arbitrary values for state. I can do "structured logging" only to the extent that all my values are contained within my message. I reasoned that it is entirely possible that I should be using scopes for these "unformatted state values" instead of state. I tried this:

```cs
var sprops = new[] {
    KeyValuePair.Create<string, object>("scope-key-1", "scope-value-1"),
    KeyValuePair.Create<string, object>("scope-key-2", 9),
};

using (var scope = _logger.BeginScope(sprops)) {
    lm(_logger, "my-formatted-value", null);
}
```

This does indeed allow me to get arbitrary "state" values in the output, but there is still some strange output:

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "2023-03-09T18:27:55",
  "EventId": 11,
  "LogLevel": "Error",
  "Category": "ConsoleApplication",
  "Message": "This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: my-formatted-value",
  "State": {
    "Message": "This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: my-formatted-value",
    "formatted_value": "my-formatted-value",
    "{OriginalFormat}": "This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: {formatted_value}"
  },
  "Scopes": [
    {
      "Message": "System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair\u00602[System.String,System.Object][]",
      "scope-key-1": "scope-value-1",
      "scope-key-2": 9
    }
  ]
}
```

The Scopes -> Message property still has a `.ToString()` on the `sprops` object. I guess I can live with this if I have to, but it feels, again, like I'm missing something. I decided to try Serilog to see if maybe they had something better to offer. I first tried just the basic console output (no JSON), and got this (I'm writing both log messages here):

```
[11:43:28 ERR] This message came from LoggerMessage.Define; the formatted value is: my-formatted-value
[11:43:28 ERR] {KeyValuePair`2[]:l}
```

That's... odd. The message written using `_logger.Log(...)` is completely useless. Instead of the output of my `formatter` lambda, I got `state.ToString()` as the message. If I have Serilog output JSON instead of plain text, things are somewhat better, but still very wrong (for the `_logger.Log(...)` output):

```json
{
  "Timestamp": "2023-03-09T11:46:17.4597182-07:00",
  "Level": "Error",
  "MessageTemplate": "{KeyValuePair`2[]:l}",
  "RenderedMessage": "{KeyValuePair`2[]:l}",
  "Properties": {
    "state-key-1": "state-value-1",
    "state-key-2": 2,
    "KeyValuePair`2[]": "This message came from _logger.Log(...); it has no formatted values.",
    "EventId": {
      "Id": 12,
      "Name": "twelve"
    },
    "SourceContext": "ConsoleApplication"
  }
}
```

The `RenderedMessage` property is wrong, the `MessageTemplate` property is wrong, the actual message comes under `Properties` and now the key is `state.ToString()` for some reason.

I have to be fundamentally misunderstanding something here; it seems unlikely that I'm the only person that has ever encountered these issues.

How do I cause the `ILogger` machinery to output JSON log messages that make sense?